# Autosuggest with files on hard drive (React / Electron)

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native, electron

I am looking to understand a general strategy here. I have hundreds of files on my hard drive, with different file names. In my React / electron application I would like to use an autosuggest tool, so that the user can type a name and then all the file names that match are being autosuggested.

How would I do this most efficiently? Would I, in a first step, grab all the file names and store them in some kind of json, linking to the actual files, and then hand that json to my autosuggest component? Or could I have direct access to the files?

What would be the most efficient way, generally speaking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are these files limited to a set you know of in advance? (i.e. not your entire drive). If so then [search-index](https://github.com/fergiemcdowall/search-index) sounds like it will do the job: *"A persistent, network resilient, full text search library for the browser and Node.js"*.

If on the other hand you need dynamic search of your entire drive, that will be harder. There is [node-spotlight](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-spotlight) for OSX, to hook into the native 'Spotlight' search engine. I don't know if there is a comparable lib for Windows. Perhaps [windows.storage.search](https://yarnpkg.com/en/package/windows.storage.search#readme)

Comment: Thank you. I know in advance that it will be a single folder with multiple, quite lightweight files - but many of them, say 1k / 10k / 100k. I am using OS X. So I guess I'll try search-index, unless what I said just now changes things significantly.

Answer (score 0):

Reading files when user is entering text will be very expensive operation as reading hard drives can be quite slow.
Prepare a list of available files and feed it to autocomplete component. You can update files list by listening to the changes broadcasted by system in hard drive or regularly updating files list.

More accurate answer can be given if you mention platform.